# Why doesn't predict like the dimensions of my newdata?

Tags: r

I want to perform a multiple regression in R and make predictions based on the trained model. Below is an example code I am using:

```
price = c(10,18,18,11,17)
predictors = cbind(c(5,6,3,4,5),c(2,1,8,5,6))
predict(lm(price ~ predictors), data.frame(predictors=matrix(c(3,5),nrow=1)))
```

So, based on the 2-variate regression model trained by 5 samples, I want to make a prediction for the test data point where the first variate is 3 and second variate is 5. But I get a warning from above code saying that `'newdata' had 1 rows but variable(s) found have 5 rows`. How can I correct above code? Below code works fine where I give the variables separately to the model formula. But since I will have hundreds of variates, I have to give them in a matrix since it would be unfeasible to append hundreds of columns  using `+` sign.

```
price = c(10,18,18,11,17)
predictor1 = c(5,6,3,4,5)
predictor2 = c(2,1,8,5,6)
predict(lm(price ~ predictor1 + predictor2), data.frame(predictor1=3,predictor2=5))
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to get past the issue of matching up variable names from a matrix of covariates to newdata data.frame column names is to put your input data into a data.frame as well. Try this

```
price <- c(10,18,18,11,17)
predictors <- cbind(c(5,6,3,4,5),c(2,1,8,5,6))
indata <- data.frame(price, predictors=predictors)

predict(lm(price ~ ., indata), data.frame(predictors=matrix(c(3, 5), nrow=1)))
```

Here we combine `price` and `predictors` into a data.frame such that it will be named the same say as the `newdata` data.frame. We use the `.` in the formula to mean "all other columns" so we don't have to specify them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Need to build the model first, then predict from it:

```
mod1 <- lm(price ~ predictor1 + predictor2)

predict( mod1 , data.frame(predictor1=3,predictor2=5))
```